# I want to convert my array into Json Array in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json

I want to convert the nsmutable array into json array in objective c but I am getting some extra characters also

My code

```
if (isSucceeded) {

NSMutableDictionary *dictFieldValue = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *fieldSelectedOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                   [fieldSelectedOptions addObject:str];


[dictFieldValue setObject:@(fieldData.fieldId) forKey:@"field_id"];
                   NSError *error;

                   NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:fieldSelectedOptions options:0 error:&error];
                 NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [dictFieldValue setObject:jsonString forKey:@"f_value"];

                [arrFieldValues addObject:dictFieldValue];
                   NSLog(@"arrFieldValues:%@",arrFieldValues);

               }
```

Output

```
    arrFieldValues:(
    {
    "field_id" = 128;
    "field_value" = 5;
},
   {
    "f_value" = "[\"1\"]";
    "field_id" = 129;
}
)
```

but i want the output like

```
arrFieldValues:(
    {
    "field_id" = 128;
    "field_value" = 5;
},
    {
    "f_value" = ["2"];
    "field_id" = 129;
}
)
```

I have convert the msmutable array into json array and then NSstring and Add that string into an another array in objective. Please let me know my mistake here.

Comment: Forget `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`.  It adds unnessary whitespace and newline characters. And what are the string manipulations and regular expression for? `NSJSONSerialization` creates the proper JSON

Comment: Thanks @vadian , then what i want to use there?

Comment: Manipulating JSON with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` and related methods is almost certainly going to screw the contents up. What are ***actually trying*** to achieve?

Comment: Please stop randomly printing the contents of the arrFieldValues, that output is meaningless. What do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: `f_value` is JSONified inside JSON. Use another NSJSONSerialization for it. Also, do not manipulate the JSON as String with `stringByReplacingMatchesInString`.

Comment: Please don't edit the question by fixing the issue. It becomes pointless for other readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` and all string manipulation code.

Replace

```
NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:fieldSelectedOptions options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
jsonString =[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
jsonString = [jsonString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[,\\.\']" options:0 error:NULL];

jsonString = [expression stringByReplacingMatchesInString:jsonString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, jsonString.length)
                                                                         withTemplate:@""];
jsonString =[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
[dictFieldValue setObject:jsonString forKey:@"f_value"];
```

with

```
NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:fieldSelectedOptions options:0 error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dictFieldValue[@"f_value"] = jsonString;
```

I'm wondering why almost all tutorials suggest the pretty printed option.

Servers don't care about aesthetics at all.

Comment: I guess tutorials uses the pretty print option for teaching reasons: It is easier to check and explain the result.

Comment: Vadian ,please check my updated code..now also i am getting some extra characters

Comment: The *extra characters* are pretty fine. The backslashes are added virtually to escape the double quotes in the literal string description.

Comment: i don't want any extra characters .i want like this **arrFieldValues:(
    {
    "field_id" = 128;
    "field_value" = 5;
},
    {
    "f_value" = ["2"];
    "field_id" = 129;
}
)**

Comment: * sigh * . Once again, **there are no extra characters**. They are added **virtually** when calling the `description` method to be able to display double quotes in a literal string.